# Vue3 v-model bind nested data property with bracket access fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue3 and facing problem that I cannot bind nested property to v-model correctly.

Here is source code:

Template:

```html
<div id="app">
  <span>{{level1.level2.level3}}</span> <br/>
  <span>{{level1['level2']['level3']}}</span> <br/>
  <input v-model="level1.level2.level3" /> <br/>
  <input v-model="level1.level2['level3']" /> <br/>
  <input v-model="level1['level2']['level3']" />
</div>
```

JS

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      level1: {
        level2: {
          level3: "val"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {}
}).mount("#app")
```

`<input v-model="level1.level2.level3" />` bind works

`<input v-model="level1.level2['level3']" />` bind works

but `<input v-model="level1['level2']['level3']" />` bind fails

The console warning said

```
"[Vue warn]: Template compilation error: v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression.
```

What's the reason `level1['level2']['level3']` not binding to v-model correctly? I think it's a valid js expression.

Here is online [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0rz9ucj/43/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is [an issue with Vue itself, not with your code.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/3910) It also seems that this issue has been fixed in [a commit](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/commit/bc100c5c48b98b6e2eabfa1d50e0d3099ea2a90d) just over a week ago.

So if you're on Vue <=3.1.1 (a.k.a any version but the current GitHub master branch), your only real solution here would be to rework how you access properties, wait for a Vue update, or depend directly on the GitHub repository's master branch (not a great idea in general, so only do this if you *need* this notation and you need it *right now*).